# How to write node for collecting data from P3AT robot

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, pioneer, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have question. I wish to collect velocity (left and right speed)data from Pioneer 3AT, and for that write node, and that data i want to use for odometry.
I ask if someone can me direct on right path. There are some tutorials but i dont know which i need to look. If someone have idea, please to give me some suggestion.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9553/how-to-write-node-for-collecting-data-from-p3at-robot/) by [Jurica](https://answers.ros.org/users/324/jurica/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2011-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Both [p2os_driver](http://www.ros.org/wiki/p2os_driver) and [ROSARIA](http://code.google.com/p/amor-ros-pkg/) publish nav_msgs/Odometry on "pose" topic. Therefore, it suffices to subscribe to the "pose" topic and collect Odometry messages.

If you really need left and right wheel velocities, you should use specific robot parameters and get those speeds from linear and angular velocities that are reported in the Odometry message.

Just one more note, ROSARIA reported Pose in [mm] prior to Feb 24, 2011. As of that date, we've fixed it to report Pose in [m].

---

Originally posted by [JKS](https://answers.ros.org/users/357/jks/) with karma: 306 on 2011-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thill@tntech.edu](https://answers.ros.org/users/24004/thill@tntech.edu/) on 2015-09-22**:
Looking at the rosaria package summary it seems that you only have access to the estimated robot velocities but not the joint (the wheels) velocities. Am I missing something?  Are these the actual measured encoder counts mapped through the kinematics or are they just the commanded robot velocities?

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2015-09-24**:
The robot controller (dedicated microcontroller inside the robot) is already doing the integration of the wheel encoders and providing the pose (x,y,th). (You can request  encoder counts using ARIA library  but this is provided mainly as a diagnostic/testing feature.)

**Comment by [josephtranminh1996](https://answers.ros.org/users/31116/josephtranminh1996/) on 2017-07-11**:
Hello! I am a very new beginner. I have a question: can I control the velocity of wheels on each side individually?